# regular expression for ends with some word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build regular expression for series

cd1_inputchk,rd_inputchk,optinputchk where inputchk is common (ending characters)

please guide for the same

Comment: Are the commas significant?  Do you need to capture anything? Please elaborate what the regex is for.  If it's just to match a single word all you need is `/inputchk$/` but let us know what you will be doing and we can help with the JavaScript.

Comment: these are different checkboxes

Answer (score 4):

Very simply, it's:

```
/inputchk$/
```

On a per-word basis (only testing matching `/inputchk$/.test(word) ? 'matches' : 'doesn\'t match';`). The reason this works, is it matches `"inputchk"` that comes at the end of a string (hence the `$`)

As for a *list* of words, it starts becoming more complicated.

- Are there spaces in the list?
- Are they needed?

I'm going to assume `no` is the answer to both questions, and also assume that the list is comma-separated.

There are then a couple of ways you could proceed. You *could* use `list.split()` to get an array of each word, and teast each to see if they end in `inputchk`, or you could use a modified regular expression:

```
/[^,]*inputchk(?:,|$)/g
```

This one's much more complicated.

- `[^,]` says to match non-`,` characters
- `*` then says to match 0 or more of those non-`,` chars. (it will be greedy)
- `inputchk` matches `inputchk`
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing parenthesis. It says to match the characters, but not store the match as part of the result.
- `,` matches the `,` character
- `|` says match one side **or** the other
- `$` says to match the end of the string

Hopefully all of this together will select the strings that you're looking for, but it's very easy to make a mistake, so I'd suggest doing some rigorous testing to make sure there aren't any edge-conditions that are being missed.

Comment: Or using word breaks: `/\w+inputchk(\b|$)/g` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

This one should work (dollar sign basically means "end of string"):

```
/inputchk$/
```

Comment: FYI the `.*` followed by text induces backtracking.  Consider a non-greedy qualifier